# How to integrate a Sharepoint Blog into ASP.NET web application?

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint

Googling did not result any useful answers so I'm trying you.

Has anyone out there ever done an integration of a Sharepoint Blog into an ASP.NET web application? Or, do you know of any sharepoint web services available for retrieving and updating sharepoint blog content? Any info is appreciated.

- Sharepoint is MOSS 2010
- The web application is a sitecore intranet
  portal 3.3 but this may be inconsequential

Comment: I looked into this before and the consensus was that it would have to be done manually...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There wouldn't be a simple solution to this, however here are a couple of approaches you could explore:

1) Consume the SharePoint Blog RSS feed in your .NET application to get the blog posts

2) Use the SharePoint Client Object Model to interact with SharePoint via custom code.  Using the object model (through C# or VB) you could create new posts (which are just list items) as well as retrieve them.  Here is a good place to start on writing custom code with the Client Object Model: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee857094.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Check this open source web part

- http://www.bendsoft.com/downloads/sharepoint-web-parts/sharepoint-blog-reader/

It would be very simple to convert to generic .net usage, contact Bendsoft at their forum (http://forum.bendsoft.com), maybe they will help you with some of the work. It isn't very difficult when using a connector.

The solution is compatible with both SP 2007, 2010 and also feature versions like 2013.